# get a dict with key as column names and value as column type of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe  as shown below:-

```
   A   B   C  D
0  56  89  16  b
1  51  41  99  b
2  49   3  72  d
3  15  98  58  c
4  92  55  77  d
```

I want to create a dict where key is column name and value is column data type.

```
dtypes = df.dtypes.to_dict()  
print(dtypes)


{'A': dtype('int64'), 'B': dtype('int64'), 'C': dtype('int64'), 'D': dtype('O')}
```

Instead of above how do I get the dict in below format:-

```
{'A': 'int64', 'B': 'int64', 'C': 'int64', 'D': 'object'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map values to `str` type:

```
df.dtypes.map(str).to_dict()
```

---

```
{'A': 'int64', 'B': 'int64', 'C': 'int64', 'D': 'object'}
```